# Adding tasks to RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and have been learning about Android app development for about a month just through a book, and right now, I'm working on my own project, which is a basic app that manages user tasks and schedule. There is this one problem I am having. I am trying to add a new task to a RecyclerView list that contains the list of main tasks, but I keep getting errors. Here is what I have (I don't want to show everything because it is a project):

The RecyclerView list (main_task_window.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/MainTaskList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="449dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="61dp" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/AddaMainTask"
    android:onClick="addnewtask"
    android:layout_width="54dp"
    android:layout_height="51dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The window that allows users to add new main tasks as well as additional notes (add_new_main_task_window.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/maintasks"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:hint="Main Task"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/notes"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp"
    android:hint="Additional notes"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/addButton"
    android:onClick="sendButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add to main task" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now here are the following Java files:
 1. MainTasks.java (contains the get and set methods for the main task and additional notes)

```
package com.ricstudios.daymanager;

public class MainTasks
{
    private String mt, an; //'mt' stands for "main tasks". 'an' stands for "additional notes"

    //MainTasks class constructor
    public MainTasks(String mt, String an)
    {
        //mt and an in the parameters is equal to the mt and an variables above
        this.mt = mt;
        this.an = an;
    }

    public String getMainTasks() //this get method obtains the main task string input)
    {
       return mt;
    }
    public void setMainTasks(String MainTasks) //this set methods stores the main task string input)
    {
       this.mt = MainTasks;
    }
    public String getAdditionalNotes() //this get method obtains the main task string input
    {
       return an;
    }
    public void setAdditionalNotes(String AddNotes) //this set method stores the main task string
    {
       this.an = AddNotes;
    }
}
```

2. MainTaskAdapter.java (contains the adapter to render the data)

```html
package com.ricstudios.daymanager;

import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import java.util.List;

public class MainTaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainTaskAdapter.ViewHolder>
{
    private List<MainTasks> maintasklist; //will contain the main task and additional notes string inputs

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        public EditText maintask, addnotes;

        //provides a reference to the views for each data item
        public ViewHolder(View view)
        {
            super(view);

            maintask = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.maintasks);
            addnotes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.notes);
        }
    }

    //MainTaskAdapter class constructor
    public MainTaskAdapter(List<MainTasks> maintasklist)
    {
        this.maintasklist = maintasklist;
    }

    //create new view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.add_new_main_task_window, parent, false);

        return new ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    //replaces the contents of the main task view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        MainTasks obj = maintasklist.get(position); //MainTasks class obj called 'obj', which allows access to the MainTasks class

        //obtains the main task and additional notes from the MainTask class
        holder.maintask.setText(obj.getMainTasks());
        holder.addnotes.setText(obj.getAdditionalNotes());
    }

    //returns the size of the main task list (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount()
    {
        return maintasklist.size();
    }
}
```

3. AddNewMainTask.java (adds the tasks and additional notes to the RecyclerView)

```html
package com.ricstudios.daymanager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/*This class handles the window for adding new main tasks to the main task list (this window is the add_new_main_task_window.xml layout)*/
public class AddNewMainTask extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private Button addbutton; //Button element from the add_new_main_task_window.xml layout
    private EditText maintask, addnotes; //EditText elements from the add_new_main_task_window.xml layout
    private List<MainTasks> maintasklist = new ArrayList<>();
    private RecyclerView ListofMainTasks; //RecyclerView list element from the add_new_main_task_window.xml layout (containing the Main Task list)
    private MainTaskAdapter TAdapter; //MainTaskAdapter class object 'TAdapter', allows access to the MainTaskAdapter class

    /*sendButton method from the Button element in the add_new_main_task_window.xml and adds the main task and additional notes to the RecyclerView main task list*/
    public void sendButton(View view)
    {
        maintask = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.maintasks);
        addnotes = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.notes);

        ListofMainTasks = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.MainTaskList);

        TAdapter = new MainTaskAdapter(maintasklist);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
        ListofMainTasks.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        ListofMainTasks.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        ListofMainTasks.setAdapter(TAdapter);

        /*Passes the EditText element values into the MainTask.java parameters*/
        MainTasks mnt = new MainTasks(maintask.getText().toString(), addnotes.getText().toString());
        maintasklist.add(mnt);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_new_main_task_window); //displays the window that allows users to add new main tasks (which is the add_new_main_task_window.xml layout)

        addbutton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);

        /*When user clicks button, the values the user puts in the EditText fields will be added to the RecyclerView list of the main_task_window.xml layout*/
        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sendButton(v);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Whenever I press the "Add to Main Task" button, the app suddenly stop. Please help. Oh, and about the floatingactionbutton in the main_task_window.xml, don't worry about that. That just sends the user to the add_new_main_task_window.xml

**Update: 3/5/19**

I'm getting this error from the logcat:
03-05 15:22:49.298 10335-10335/com.project.daymanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.project.daymanager, PID: 10335
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
        at com.project.daymanager.AddNewMainTask.sendButton(AddNewMainTask.java:39)
        at com.project.daymanager.AddNewMainTask$1.onClick(AddNewMainTask.java:63)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5702)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:10887)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22541)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Can you post what is the error you getting?

Comment: instead of doing `(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.maintasks);` please do `findViewById(R.id.maintasks);`

Comment: I'm not getting errors after building it. The app runs successfully, but when I press the "Add to Main Task" button, the app suddenly crashes

Comment: if you check your logcat in android studio, it surely gives you exception of your crash. look for it and paste it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Replace 
   `view.findViewById();`
   with
   `findViewById();`
2. In the `MainTasks.java` Don't use a constructor

`public MainTasks(String mt, String an)`
Just keep the set And get methods and do

```
 MainTasks mt = new MainTasks();
 mt.setMainTasks("Title");
 mt.setAdditionalNotes("Note");
 list.add(mt);
```

If it still not working, please post the error log so we can know whats the error.

**Update: 3/5/19**

You are trying to access the `recyclerView` of the `MainTaskActivity` in

`ListofMainTasks = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.MainTaskList);`

from out side the activity (From another Activity) and that's not possible this way,

you can set the `RecyclerView` in the `MainTaskActivity` to `static` and use it in `AddNewMainTask` Activity by calling it
`MainTaskActivity.myRecyclerView`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line:

```
 ListofMainTasks = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.MainTaskList);
```

program is unable to find recycler view and its null. and you can't set layout manager to a null object. I've reviewed your code and thing you did wrong is that in you onCreate method you are setting layout `setContentView(R.layout.add_new_main_task_window);` and you're trying to find recylerview which is not in this layout.

Your recycler view is in **main_task_window.xml**. use `setContentView(R.layout.main_task_window.xml);` and your activity will find recyclerview easily.

Note: if you want button/controls also which are in this layout **add_new_main_task_window.xml** then please move them in layout with recyclerview.